# Instance variable not showing in view forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm having issues getting an instance variable to show up in my views. I'm setting it using a private method, and I'm using a before_filter to ensure that I can access it in the two places I need it. However, the instance variable is not showing up in the view, let alone having the needed action.

In my controller I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :set_form, :only => [ :edit_password, :edit_email ]
...
def edit_password 
@user = current_user
  set_form('password') 
end 
def edit_email
  @user = current_user
  set_form('email')
end
...
private
def set_form(edit_type)
  @form = edit_type
end
```

Here is the view file

```
<h1>Edit Your Account</h1>

<title><%= @form %></title>
<% if @form == 'email' %>
<%= render 'edit_email_form' %>
<% else %> 
<%= render 'edit_password_form' %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', user_path(@user) %>
```

I'm not sure what else I need to do to be able to use the instance variable in the view. I'm also wondering whether it's still possible to access the instance variable in the update statement after? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no value in setting `set_form` in a before_filter, as you're calling it in your methods.

You need to explicitly render your view file... I don't see you're doing that.  If the form is called (for example) `edit_value.html.erb` then your two `edit_...` methods need to have

```
render :edit_value
```

Instance values are not available in the update statement. When you update nothing is available except the information submitted in your form or url, or anything you saved in the `session` hash, or anything you persisted to your database.

Comment: thanks! Is it ok do that kind of thing in a view? or is that not supposed to be allowed in the rails MVC framework?

Comment: It's allowed, but generally you want to minimize logic in a view as much as possible. If I were writing this, I would have `edit_password` and `edit_email` render separate views. If there's any stuff that should be in common between the two (like your `link_to :back`) I would put that in a partial that's called by both forms..